# How to know how many times Coundown timer start and finish in android?

Tags: android

I have a countdown timer of 30 seconds which starts when app is open.

On every time this timer start and finish, I want to show new activity.

How could I do that?

Comment: @vishwas check my answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

First of all start a `Timer` for 30 seconds.
`Onfinish` method of the timer update how many times timer have been finished in `shared prefferences`.
Here is the full code.

First define

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
```

and in onCreate of your `activity` or `fragment`

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Now make your timer

```
int oneMin= 30 * 1000; // 30 seconds in milli seconds

    /** CountDownTimer starts with 30 seconds and every onTick is 1 second */
    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(oneMin, 1000) {


        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.e("timer","time");
            // this method is invoke in every 1 second (1000 milli second )
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            // you can also check here how many times this timer have been finished in past
            // this method will invoke after completion that is 30 seconds
            Intent intent = new Intent (context, NewActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            // you can save in SHARED PREFFERENCES and update how many times this method is invoked.
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            int times = sharedpreferences.getInt("times",0);
            editor.putInt("times",times);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please edit your answer to explain your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
       //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
        //start new activity here
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewActivityName.class);
        startActivity(intent)
    }

}.start();
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please edit your answer to explain your code (and indent it properly - highlight and use the code block button on the toolbar).

Answer (score 0):

For this You should have two `Activities`

**MainActivity:**  Launcher Activity

**TempActivity:** Temp Activity for 30 seconds

`TimeFlag` is false by default so you will direct to your `TempActivity` where you something for 30 seconds then `TimeFlag` will become true and your `MainActivity` set the content.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static boolean TimeFlag = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!TimeFlag) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TempActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            // your other task here below
        }
    }
}
```

**TempActivity:**

```
public class TempActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int Tick = 1000;
    public static final int Complete = 30000; // 30 seconds

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp);


        CountDownTimer timmer = new CountDownTimer(Complete, Tick) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.e("timer", "time");
                // this method is invoke in every 1 second (1000 milli second )
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                MainActivity.TimeFlag = true;
                finish();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```